# How to get this to work in IE10 or IE9 or IE 8

Tags: jquery, jomsocial

I have this simple jomsocial jquery function that works perfect in Chrome, Safari and FireFox. But does not want to work in any IE version.

See my code, please help

```
joms.jQuery('#player-notice a.close').click(function(){
/alert('shoot click works boss');
    joms.jQuery("#player-fp").attr('src', '');
joms.jQuery('#player-notice-wrapper').slideUp();
if (jQuery.browser.msie) {joms.jQuery('#player-notice-wrapper').hide();}
return false;
});
```

If you notice I even tried the jquery.msie feature and still did not work.

joms.jquery, is the joomla jquery library. But it works on every other browser. Except IE.

Need to figure the fix..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question leaves me wondering what it should do and what part of that it doesn't do. Perhaps if I knew more about joomla or jomsjquery, it would be clear.

Comment: have you tried it without the `joms.` before the `jQuery` on every statement? I am not familiar with joomla or jomsjquery but if jquery is loaded then it should work without the `joms.` And if `joms.` is required then it may also be required within the if condition before the `jQuery`.

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: `/alert('shoot click works boss');` looks incorrect.. should this be commented out? if so, it should be `//` not a singular `/`

Comment: jQuery.browser was deprecated in version 1.3 and removed in version 1.9

Comment: well... you should start by not hiding it in all versions of IE.... too obvious?

Comment: We figured it out. There was an open tage pointing to'iframe', this is not a respect way to target iframes in jquery.

Got it working correctly for IE10 & IE9, but IE 8 and IE7 is not working.

We can live with that.

IE8 we will not support neither IE7, for this product.